# Add blank spaces in the beginning and end of each line C#

Tags: c#, windows, string, line

I am creating a program for chords. I need a space in the beginning of each line and at the end of the each line, so program can identify chords.Here is the replacement as it goes, but I don't know how to add blank spaces.

```
 richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(" H ", " X ").Replace(" A# ", " H ").Replace(" A ", " A# ").Replace(" G# ", " A ").Replace(" G ", " G# ").Replace(" F# ", " G ").Replace(" F ", " F# ")
               .Replace(" E ", " F ").Replace(" D# ", " E ").Replace(" D ", " D# ").Replace(" C# ", " D ").Replace(" C ", " C# ").Replace(" X ", " C ")


               .Replace(" Hm ", " Xm ").Replace(" A#m ", " Hm ").Replace(" Am ", " A#m ").Replace(" G#m ", " Am ").Replace(" Gm ", " G#m ").Replace(" F#m ", " Gm ").Replace(" Fm ", " F#m ")
               .Replace(" Em ", " Fm ").Replace(" D#m ", " Em ").Replace(" Dm ", " D#m ").Replace(" C#m ", " Dm ").Replace(" Cm ", " C#m ").Replace(" Xm ", " Cm ");
```

Comment: You are unfamiliar with the space character?

Comment: Why don't you use `richTextBox1.Lines` to modify each line separately(f.e. via `for`-loop)?

Comment: I see a lot of problems. First, you do `Replace(" H ", " X ")` and later on `Replace(" X ", " C ")`. I don't understand your initial problem, but this one is another.

Comment: you should not work on RichText. Extract the 'contents' do your modifications, the build RichText from your contents.

Comment: ok,how to do that exactly? I mean how to make spaces at the beggining and at the end of each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create text file with some lines (each line with no space in the begining and at the end) like:
H X
A# H
A A#
G# A
G G#
F# G
F F#
and this is the code for making new file with space in front and at the end of each line I hope this will be as you want:

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
namespace StringLineSpaceAdd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TextReader r = File.OpenText(@"D:\myFile.txt");
            string currentLine="";
            HashSet<string> previousLines = new HashSet<string>();
            TextWriter w = File.CreateText(@"D:\\newFile.txt");
            while ((currentLine = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Add returns true if it was actually added,
                // false if it was already there
                if (previousLines.Add(currentLine))
                {
                    currentLine = " " + currentLine + " ";
                    w.WriteLine(currentLine);
                }
            }
            w.Close();
        }
    }
}`